# In this sequence, pattern $\{0,1,1\}$ will continue forever?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations

Define radical of an integer [Wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_an_integer)

$$\displaystyle{\mathrm{rad}}(n)=\prod_{{\scriptstyle p\mid n\atop p\:{\text{prime}}}}p$$

Example $n=504=2^3\cdot3^2\cdot7$ therefore ${\displaystyle \operatorname{rad}(504)=2\cdot3\cdot7=42}$

Define recurrence relation $a_k=\operatorname{rad}(a_{k-1}+a_{k-2})$ for $k\ge 2$ where $a_0=0,a_1=1$.

Sequence as https://oeis.org/A165911

$\{a_0,a_1,a_2,...\} = \{0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 2, 7, 3, 10, 13, 23, 6, 29, 35, 2, 37, 39, 38,...\}$

It is not known that sequence stuck in any loop. We can observe following pattern

Introduce the positive difference operator, $∆$, on sequence $\{a_k\}$, which gives a new sequence, defined $∆a_k$ as $\mid a_{k}-a_{k-1}\mid$.
In general $∆^ta_k=\mid ∆^{t-1}a_{k}-∆^{t-1}a_{k-1}\mid$

$$\displaystyle{\begin{array}{c}∆^0a_0\quad ∆^0a_1\quad ∆^0a_2\quad ...\\∆^1a_0\quad ∆^1a_1\quad ...\\∆^2a_0\quad ...\\ \ddots \end{array}}$$

Let convert sequence $\{a_k\}$

$$\displaystyle{\begin{array}{c}0\quad 1\quad 1\quad  2\quad 3\quad 5\quad 2\quad 7\quad 3\quad 10\quad 13\quad 23\quad 6\quad 29\quad 35... \\ \ 1\quad 0\quad 1\quad  1\quad 2\quad 3\quad 5\quad 4\quad 7\quad 3\quad 10\quad 17\quad 23\quad 6 ...\\1\quad 1\quad 0\quad  1\quad 1\quad 2\quad 1\quad 3\quad 4\quad 7\quad 7\quad 6\quad 17...\\0\quad 1\quad 1\quad  0\quad 1\quad 1\quad 2\quad 1\quad 3\quad 0\quad 1\quad 11...\\1\quad 0\quad 1\quad  1\quad 0\quad 1\quad 1\quad 2\quad 3\quad 1\quad 10...\\1\quad 1\quad 0\quad  1\quad 1\quad 0\quad 1\quad 1\quad 2\quad 9...\\0\quad 1\quad 1\quad  0\quad 1\quad 1\quad 0\quad 1\quad 7...\\1\quad 0\quad 1\quad  1\quad 0\quad 1\quad 1\quad 6...\\1\quad 1\quad 0\quad  1\quad 1\quad 0\quad 5...\\0\quad 1\quad 1\quad  0\quad 1\quad 5...\\1\quad 0\quad 1\quad  1\quad 4...\\1\quad 1\quad 0\quad  3...\\0\quad 1\quad 3...\\1\quad 2...\\1...\\ \quad \ddots
 \end{array}}$$

**Observation**: The 1st diagonal shows period of order 3 with $\{0,1,1\}$ repeating cycle.

> In first diagonal, can it be shown that the pattern $\{0,1,1\}$ will continue forever?

---

*I have not been checked by programming. Thank you*

Comment: Note this is somewhat related to [Gilbreath's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbreath%27s_conjecture). In your case, since the first line, taken in groups of $3$, are always of the form of even, odd and odd, this means the left diagonal will also always be of the same form. However, as Varun Vejall's answer shows, it's not always going to be a $\{0, 1, 1\}$ repeating cycle, although I suspect (but don't know how to prove or disprove) there might be an infinite number of occurrences of a $\{0, 1, 1\}$ cycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern only holds for the first $21$ rows. It's noteworthy that it even held for that many rows, but after that, it doesn't work.

Using the OEIS entry, I found that $\Delta^{21}a_0 = 14$ when it should have been $0$. Here is the Python code I used to check this.

```
#L holds the entries from A165911
D = [L]
while len(D[-1]) >= 2:
    newD = []
    for i in range(len(D[-1])-1):
        newD.append(abs(D[-1][i+1]-D[-1][i]))
    D.append(newD)

for i in range(len(D)):
    if i%3 == 0 and D[i][0] != 0:
        print(i)
        break
    if i%3 != 0 and D[i][0] != 1:
        print(i)
        break
```

Output: `21`

Answer (score 2):

I did the exact same thing in C, using the first $50$ terms.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int c[50]={-omitted-};
    int a[50][50];
    int i,j;
    for (i=0;i<50;i++)
        a[0][i]=c[i];
    for (j=1;j<50;j++)
        for (i=0;i<50-j;i++)
            a[j][i]=abs (a[j-1][i+1]-a[j-1][i]);
    for (j=0;j<50;j++)
        printf("%d, ", a[j][0]);
}
```

Output:

```
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 14, 13, 1, 8, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 15, 9, 8, 7, 7, 2, 1, 1, 0, 3, 3, 2, 1,
```

It seems that there are still some traces of $1,1,0$ in the latter terms.